# jQuery target next() html item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi I have a list of items which is generated like so:

```
    <li class="panel-title">Item 1<i class="fa pull-right fa-plus"></i></li>
    <ul class="panel-body">...</ul>
    <li class="panel-title">Item 2<i class="fa pull-right fa-plus"></i></li>
    <ul class="panel-body">...</ul>
    <li class="panel-title">Item 3<i class="fa pull-right fa-plus"></i></li>
    <ul class="panel-body">...</ul>
```

Upon clicking an 'li' item I need only the next 'ul' to expand. Unsure how to solve this & whether next() is the right action
Heres my code

```
  $('li.panel-title > .fa').on("click",function() {
  var $currIcon = $(this); 
  var $contents = $('ul.panel-body');         
  if($currIcon.hasClass('fa-plus')) {   

          $currIcon.$contents.next().slideDown();             
          $currIcon.removeClass('fa-plus');
          $currIcon.addClass('fa-minus');             
  } else if($currIcon.hasClass('fa-minus')) {             
          $currIcon.$contents.next().slideUp();                   
          $currIcon.removeClass('fa-minus');
          $currIcon.addClass('fa-plus');
  }  
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('li.panel-title > .fa').on("click",function() {
  var $currIcon = $(this); 
  var $contents = $('ul.panel-body');         
  if($currIcon.hasClass('fa-plus')) {
          $currIcon.parent().next().slideDown();             
          $currIcon.removeClass('fa-plus');
          $currIcon.addClass('fa-minus');             
  } else if($currIcon.hasClass('fa-minus')) {             
          $currIcon.parent().next().slideUp();                   
          $currIcon.removeClass('fa-minus');
          $currIcon.addClass('fa-plus');
  }  
 });
```

Comment: Awesome thanks mate! Works, although doesn't look like I need this line anymore var $contents = $('ul.panel-body'); . Thx

Answer (score 0):

Below is jQuery Code:

```
$('li.panel-title > .fa').on("click", function() {
    var $currIcon = $(this);
    var $contents = $($(this).closest('li').next().children('ul'));

    if ($currIcon.hasClass('fa-plus')) {
        $contents.slideDown();
        $currIcon.removeClass('fa-plus');
        $currIcon.addClass('fa-minus');
    } else if ($currIcon.hasClass('fa-minus')) {
        $contents.slideUp();
        $currIcon.removeClass('fa-minus');
        $currIcon.addClass('fa-plus');
    }
});
```

I appended a codepen. I modified HTML markup a little bit, since `ul` is directly beneath its parent node `ul`.

http://codepen.io/wooljs/pen/pEgbkB

Comment: Hi there thanks for your efforts. Unfortunately this did not work for me? @bbonch answer did work

Comment: @RRowan Thanks for replying. Did you check the modification? I removed "panel-body" from `ul` and added it to each new `li` above that `ul`.